# why webpack can't find loader

Tags: javascript, node.js, unix, npm, webpack

Here's my pacjage.json:

```
{
  "name": "redux-todo",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server"
  },

  "devDependencies": {
    "babel": "^6.5.2",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.5",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.13.2",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.11.1",
      "webpack": "^1.13.2"
   },
  "dependencies": {
   "react": "^15.3.1",
    "react-dom": "^15.3.1",
    "react-redux": "^4.4.5",
     "redux": "^3.5.2"
  }
}
```

webpack.config.js:

```
var path = require('path');

module.exports = {
entry: './index.js',
output: {
    path: './',
    filename: 'app.js'
},
devServer: {
    inline: true,
    port: 3334
},
resolveLoader: { root: path.join(__dirname, "node_modules") },
module: {
    loaders: [
        {
            test: /\.js$/,
            exclude: '/node_modules',
            loader: 'babel',
            query: {
                presets: ['es2015', 'react']
            }
        }
    ]
}
};
```

and I have following project directory structure:

```
├── actions.js
├── components
├── containers
├── index.js
├── node_modules
├── package.json
├── reducers.js
├── test.js
└── webpack.config.js
```

the absolute path to project dir is `/home/dmitriy/WebstormProjects/Redux-todo`

so why when I run `npm start` it crashes with error:

> ERROR in (webpack)/~/process/browser.js
>   Module build failed: Error: Couldn't find preset "es2015" relative to directory "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/process"

what's this `/usr/local/lib/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/process` path and why it says that it searches relative to it?

Googling this error I found that

> IMPORTANT: The loaders here are resolved relative to the resource which they are applied to. This means they are not resolved relative the the configuration file. If you have loaders installed from npm and your node_modules folder is not in a parent folder of all source files, webpack cannot find the loader. You need to add the node_modules folder as absolute path to the resolveLoader.root option. (resolveLoader: { root: path.join(__dirname, "node_modules") })

should fix it, but as you can see I have it in my config and still seeing this error.

I'm on ubuntu 16.04 LTS, nodejs version is 4.2.6, npm 3.5.2

Comment: In there any .babelrc file in your parent directory?

Comment: no, there's no .babelrc

Answer (score 1):

You are only excluding `/node_modules` as absolute path:

```
exclude: '/node_modules'
```

If you want to *recursively* exclude all `node_modules` try using:

```
exclude: /node_modules/
```

The difference is subtle but the former is using a string with an absolute path to the root `node_modules` and the latter a regular expression that matches any path with `node_modules`.

This should work without the `resolveLoader` configuration. So you can remove this field:

```
resolveLoader: { root: path.join(__dirname, "node_modules") },
```

Comment: I don't see how excluding node modules is related to the fact the webpack couldn't resolve a preset - as you can see in a final version of config I still don't have a trailing slash after node_modules and yet it works.

Comment: Because `/usr/local/lib/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/process` is not excluded. It is not in your project folder (inside your project `node_modules`). It was probably installed globally. Your babel loader shouldn't even process those files :). I prefer using `include` instead of `exclude`. It is more explicit and less error prone.

Answer (score 0):

actually I removed node_modules, tweaked package.json a little bit:

```
{
  "name": "redux-todo",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
  "start": "webpack-dev-server"
  },
 "dependencies": {
    "babel": "^6.5.2",
   "react": "^15.3.1",
   "react-dom": "^15.3.1",
    "react-redux": "^4.4.5",
    "redux": "^3.5.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
   "babel-core": "^6.13.2",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.5",
   "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.13.2",
   "babel-preset-react": "^6.11.1",
   "webpack": "^1.13.2",
   "webpack-dev-server": "^1.14.1"
 }
}
```

aaand it worked. Not sure why. Here's how webpack config looks like now:

```
var path = require('path');

module.exports = {
entry: './index.js',
output: {
    path: './',
    filename: 'app.js'
},
devServer: {
    inline: true,
    port: 3334
},
module: {
    loaders: [
        {
            test: /\.js$/,
            exclude: '/node_modules',
            loader: 'babel',
            query: {
                presets: ['es2015', 'react']
            }
        }
    ]
}
};
```

I have no clue what was that about ¯_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 0):

For my project the loader is configured like this:

```
{
  test: /\.js$/,
  exclude: '/node_modules',
  loader: "babel-loader"
}
```

And the `.babelrc` file contains this:

```
{
  "presets": ["es2015","react"]
}
```

Watching the first config of webpack that you have posted, I noticed the option `resolveLoader: { root: path.join(__dirname, "node_modules") }`. This option isn't needed if you have all loader on correct path (`node_modules` directory on project root).

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean to use `babel-loader`? If so, and if there is no `babel-loader` folder in `node_modules`, then `npm install babel-loader@7.1.1 --save-dev` should fix the issue and generate that folder.